# How to allow duplicate column names in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and I want to update column names for this data frame. The column names have duplicate entries. The below code gives error: 'cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

```
list=['alpha', 'beta','gamma', 'alpha']
df=pd.DataFrame(datframe,columns=list)
```

Comment: your initial dataframe is not defined, so it's hard to tell exactly what's going on. in any case, I would use `dataframe.rename(columns=<dict>)`

Comment: You can just assign the columns: `df.columns = ['alpha', 'beta','gamma', 'alpha']`. But I'd be careful. Now it can be very confusing whether something like `df['alpha']` returns a Series (which in most cases it _should_) but in your case now returns a DataFrame. Also a lot of basic functionality like `df.groupby('alpha')` is now broken.

Comment: Agree with @ALollz. I see little good use for having duplicate column names

Comment: yes, agree, having duplicate columns is very risky