# How to merge two data frames having same column names horizontally on basis of similar values in one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames as shown below:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 36 | 1 | type-1 |
| Blue | 78 | 2 | type-1 |
| Green | 59 | 3 | type-1 |

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | 78 | 5 | type-2 |
| Purple | 59 | 7 | type-2 |
| Brown | 36 | 9 | type-2 |

I want to merge the above two data frames on the basis of column B and after merge I want to keep the same columns as shown below:

| A | B | C | D | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 36 | 1 | type-1 | Brown | 36 | 9 | type-2 |
| Blue | 78 | 2 | type-1 | Orange | 78 | 5 | type-2 |
| Green | 59 | 3 | type-1 | Purple | 59 | 7 | type-2 |

Is it possible to do this using pandas or any other python function?

I have tried using pd.merge function but I needed to change the column names. There exists another function called pd.concat but can I provide the column name (column 'B') in it for merging?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is reason for duplicated columns names?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to parameters `left_on` and `right_on` columns from both DataFrames, so is created helper column `key_0`, which is removed after join by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

*Notice: Pandas has problem with duplicated columns names, it is reason why `merge` rename them by suffix `_x` and `_y`*

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1.B, right_on=df2.B).drop('key_0', axis=1)
print (df)
     A_x  B_x  C_x     D_x     A_y  B_y  C_y     D_y
0    Red   36    1  type-1   Brown   36    9  type-2
1   Blue   78    2  type-1  Orange   78    5  type-2
2  Green   59    3  type-1  Purple   59    7  type-2
```

What is problem with same columns names:

If need select column first `A` expected ouput is get Series.

```
print (df.A_x)
0      Red
1     Blue
2    Green
Name: A_x, dtype: object
```

But if duplicated names get all columns in DataFrame, **DONT DO IT**:

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
# print (df)

print (df.A)
       A       A
0    Red   Brown
1   Blue  Orange
2  Green  Purple
```

Answer (score 1):

apply `rename` to jezrael's anwer and you will get desired output

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1.B, right_on=df2.B).drop('key_0', axis=1)
       .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0]))
```

`out`

```
    A       B   C   D       A       B   C   D
0   Red     36  1   type-1  Brown   36  9   type-2
1   Blue    78  2   type-1  Orange  78  5   type-2
2   Green   59  3   type-1  Purple  59  7   type-2
```

Comment: Please dont rename columns names, because then problem with selecting. It is bad idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590138/how-to-allow-duplicate-column-names-in-pandas-dataframe#comment117715605_66590138

Comment: @jezrael Who doesn't know that duplicate indexes affect select? I don't think any comments are needed to give  answer questioner wants. It can be his final desired output.  and duplicated columns also have advantages when aggregating by columns.

Answer (score 0):

it's really not a good idea to have duplicated column names, but we can use a multiindex, as for me it has more sence:

```
# initial column names after join
Index(['A_x', 'B_x', 'C_x', 'D_x', 'A_y', 'B_y', 'C_y', 'D_y'], dtype='object')

# convert to multiindex
d = df.columns.groupby(df.columns.str.extract('_(.+)')[0])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(k,c.split('_')[0]) for k,v in d.items() for c in v])

# the result
       x                      y               
       A   B  C       D       A   B  C       D
0    Red  36  1  type-1   Brown  36  9  type-2
1   Blue  78  2  type-1  Orange  78  5  type-2
2  Green  59  3  type-1  Purple  59  7  type-2
```